# How do I access data inside an array initialized by constructors in a derived class?

Tags: c++

Say I make a class `collection`

```
#ifndef COLLECTION_H
#define COLLECTION_H

#include <array>


class collection
{
protected:

    std::array<std::shared_ptr<items>, 4> m_item;

public:

    collection(std::array<std::shared_ptr<items>, 4> item)
        : m_item(item)
    {}

    auto operator[] (size_t index) { return m_item(index); };


};

#endif //COLLECTION_H
```

and I create a child class `items` that initializes the data members inside the parent class

```
#include "collection.h"
#include "items.h"

class variation_1 : public collection
{
public:
    variation_1() : Base(        {std::make_shared<item_1>(),
                                  std::make_shared<item_2>(),
                                  std::make_shared<item_3>(),
                                  std::make_shared<item_4>()}) {}
};
```

I used shared pointers inside the array because I have another class with its own set of functions that initialize the data members of an item class.

```
//items.h file

#ifndef ITEMS_H
#define ITEMS_H

#include <string>

class items
{
protected:
    std::string m_ItemName;
    int m_Cost;
public:
    items(const std::string& name, int cost)
        : m_ItemName(name), m_Cost(cost)
    {}

    virtual std::string getItemName() const { return this->m_ItemName; };
    virtual int getItemCost() const { return this->m_Cost; };
};

#endif //ITEMS_H
```

```
#include "items.h"

class item_1 : public items
{
public:
    item_1() : items("Item 1", 40)
    {}

};

//and so on and so forth..
```

My question is, how do I access and print the different values inside the item array every time a new object of data type `collection` is created? Also, I'm still very new to this, so I'm not entirely sure if I am using the `shared_ptr` correctly. If there are better ways to go about this, I'd appreciate it if you'd point me (*pun not intended*) in the right direction.

Comment: `public base_Aux` -> `public items`? `Base(` -> `collection(`?

Comment: How about a `print` function in the base `item` (or `base_Aux`?) class?

Comment: About shared_ptr: You only need them if the objects are shared by other classes that might live longer than your collection. If so, it's the right choice, otherwise, it's overkill.

Comment: Your code snippets (or the classes defined in them) aren't actually related to each other in the way your description implies.  Because of that your question is unclear.   Read up on providing a [mcve].

Comment: @Peter @KamilCuk sorry about that, I edited the last snippet to use ```items``` as the base class.

Comment: @Aconcagua so should I just use raw function pointers? How would I retrieve each individual item and print their contents (price || name)?

Comment: Well, inside the collection, you use the objects directly. `std::array<MyClass, N>`; From outside, you can use raw pointers or references to these objects. **But** you need to guarantee that the objects in the collection live at least as long as the pointers or references to are still in use! If you violate that condition, you end up in undefined behaviour. So if you are not **100% sure**, then stay with the shared pointers.

Comment: So with the shared pointers, what would the syntax be like? If i create ```collection Collection```, how would I access a specific item from a variation inside the array?

Comment: @Aconcagua forgot to tag you, my bad

Comment: As is now, not at all. Why? The array is protected and you have no public accessor. You would yet provide an index operator, e. g. `auto operator[](size_t index) { return m_arr[index]; }`. Then having that you can retrieve the data as `auto value = Collection[12]; someFunction(Collection[10]);` Shared pointers come with their own overloads for `operator*` and `operator->`, so you can use these just as if they were raw pointers (in most situations at least).

Comment: @Aconcagua I made the necessary operator, but now it won't compile, showing the error: _E0980: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type_, highlighting the ```m_item``` in the ```auto operator``` line. I edited the snippets above to show the current state of my code.

Comment: Have a close look at how you defined your operator: `return m_item(index);` vs. `return m_item[index];` – have you noticed that I used brackets, not parentheses?